# Deep copy of immutable

Tags: java, immutability

Is it correct to say that immutable objects are created by deep copy everytime we want to change/reference original object, while mutable objects are created by shallow copy when we create another reference.

For example:

```
   String s1 = "s";
   String s2 = s1;
```

and:

```
   Person p1 = new Person();
   Person p2 = p1;
```

As far as I'm concerned, s2 will get it own copy of "s" (not a copy of reference).
How this fit the String pool concept with single instances of String literals?
In case of Person we will have two references to one Person instance right?

Comment: in your second example you're not making a shallow copy, but creating a second reference to the same instance

Comment: None of the cases create a second object. Only the reference is copied.

Comment: There is no deep copying in there at all. I think you have some concepts mixed up. Can you tell us where you got the notion that assigning an immutable object gives you a new copy?

Comment: While not related to this example, you do bring it up. The string pool is used in cases like `String s1 = "s"; String s2 = "s"` . While it is not guaranteed, in most cases these strings will be stored in the string pool and `s1 == s2` will return true.

Comment: here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BNBIFv9fQU&list=PLQbJEegbex4vzZ_3qWmIgZOzG-mL37vr-&index=4

Answer (score 2):

*Immutable* objects cannot be changed. Their state remains constant after creation. Thus, "s" is constant. But the references that point to it could change.

```
String s1 = "s";
String s2 = s1;
```

Here, "s" is an immutable object (String), `s1` and `s2`are just references.

**Defensive copies** are used to prevent state changes on an Object - *part of the immutability story* , by returning a new Object with the same values.

PS : You are not doing deep copying here. You are just re-assigning references.

Comment: Could you take a look at this 5 min tut and tell me if this guys is right?  My whole understanding of this concept depends on his explanation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BNBIFv9fQU&list=PLQbJEegbex4vzZ_3qWmIgZOzG-mL37vr-&index=4